# Unexpected Symbol in string implode

Tags: php

I am using implode to create a query string but there is an unexpected symbol appearing in it and im unsure where it is coming from

If anyone has any insight it would be much appreciated.

```
$url = "https://mypay.com/billing/signup.cgi";



$key = "11";
$key .= "11";
$key .= "GBP";
$key .= "QQDNfAHlC2WEEfhfhFFdhbdf";

$variables[] = "?formDigest=".md5($key);
$variables[] = "clientAccnum=1111";
$variables[] = "clientSubacc=1111";
$variables[] = "formName=108ck";
$variables[] = "formPrice=11";
$variables[] = "formPeriod=11";
$variables[] = "currencyCode=GBP";


$url .= implode("&", $variables);

echo $url;
```

The String

`https://bill.ccbill.com/jpost/signup.cgi?formDigest=df03f2b103f79bd5de34c6cfea405ec5&clientAccnum=1111&clientSubacc=1111&formName=108ck&formPrice=11&formPeriod=11¤cyCode=GBP`

notice the `¤` symbol where currencyCode should be.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: The symbol is `&curren;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`implode` works fine.

The problem here is that you are outputting HTML text (`echo $url`) but you are not properly encoding HTML special characters with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

When the browser sees the substring `&currencyCode=GBP` it guesses that you must have meant `&curren;Code=GBP`; `&curren;` is the [HTML entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) for the currency symbol, so that's what you see on the screen.

Change the code to `echo htmlspecialchars($url)` to see an immediate difference; for a fully correct solution, *pay attention to and give correct values for the first three arguments of `htmlspecialchars`*.

Answer (score -1):

"**&curren**" will be displayed that way... change the variable name "**currencyCode**" to something else and it will work

Regards

Sudeep